# ELB redirecting 443/80 to single port on nginx docker container

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb

We have a public AWS ELB that is redirecting traffic like so:

```
HTTP    80  HTTP    9001
TCP     443 TCP     9001
```

The target instance is an AWS ECS instance that is running docker with an nginx container.

Docker is forwarding 9001 -> 8080, and nginx is listening on 8080.
Here is a snipped of the nginx config:

```
server {
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/mydomain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/mydomain.key;

    listen 8080;
    server_name %{ROUTER_CLEARCARE_SERVER_NAME};

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  logstash_json;


    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != 'https') {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    set $target_web "web.mydomain.com:80";
    location / {
        proxy_read_timeout 180;
        proxy_connect_timeout 2;
        proxy_send_timeout 180;
        keepalive_timeout  180;
        resolver 10.10.0.2 valid=30s;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://$target_web;
        proxy_set_header X-Unique-ID $request_id;
    }
}
```

I need to do SSL termination on the nginx container because we have multiple certs for multiple domains, and we are using path based routing with different timeouts (ELBs only support a single cert, and ALB do not support path based routing with different timeouts and certs).

Here is the kicker: nginx can only only listen on one port (we are using a tool called Empire to deploy nginx container to AWS ECS and they currently only support this configuration).

Can nginx support http and https on a single port?

Right now, with that configuration, I get this error when trying to hit http://example.com:

```
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

And I get this error when I try to hit https://example.com I get this error:

```
mydomain.com redirected you too many times.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a statement that listening to HTTP and HTTPS should be possible for NginX on [this serverfault page (check out 2nd answer from Komu)](https://serverfault.com/questions/47876/handling-http-and-https-requests-using-a-single-port-with-nginx). I repeat it below, so you can find it more easily. Can you try it? If you are not bound to NginX, you might als be interested in [this node.js plugin](https://github.com/mscdex/httpolyglot), which also allows to listen for HTTP and HTTPS on the same port.

---

> quoted from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/47876/handling-http-and-https-requests-using-a-single-port-with-nginx):
>
> According to wikipedia article on status codes, Nginx has a custom
>   error code when http traffic is sent to https port (error code 497)
>
> And according to nginx docs on error_page, you can define a URI that
>   will be shown for a specific error. Thus we can create a uri that
>   clients will be sent to when error code 497 is raised.
>
> ```
> #lets assume your IP address is 89.89.89.89 and also that you want nginx to listen on port 7000 and your app is running on port 3000
>
> server {
>     listen 7000 ssl;
>
>     ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl_certificate.cer;
>     ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl_certificate_key.key;
>     ssl_client_certificate /path/to/ssl_client_certificate.cer;
>
>     error_page 497 301 =307 https://89.89.89.89:7000$request_uri;
>
>     location / {
>         proxy_pass http://89.89.89.89:3000/;
>
>         proxy_pass_header Server;
>         proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
>         proxy_redirect off;
>         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
>         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> However if a client makes a request via any other method except a GET,
>   that request will be turned into a GET. Thus to preserve the request
>   method that the client came in via; we use error processing redirects
>   as shown in nginx docs on error_page
>
> And thats why we use the 301 =307 redirect.
>
> Using the nginx.conf file shown here, we are able to have http and
>   https listen in on the same port